# Unwanted output formatting when passing lists and strings

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, output

I've been tasked to write a program in python to fit a given (and unchangeable) "driver" program which makes a Set class consisting of a single variable of a list called "members."

My problem is that output for the methods "has_subset()" and "intersect()" do not display properly. There are unnecessary parenthesis, commas, and apostrophes in the output.

Here is the set class:

```
class Set:
def __init__(self):
    self.members = []

def add_element(self, integer):
    if integer not in self.members:
        self.members.append(integer)

def remove_element(self, integer):
    while integer in self.members: self.members.remove(integer)

def remove_all(self):
    self.members = []

def has_element(self, x):
    while x in self.members: return True
    return False

# probably doesnt work, __repr__
def __repr__(self):
    if len(self.members) == 0:
        return "{}"
    return "{" + ", ".join(str(e) for e in self.members) + "}"

#Same as above, probably doesnt work
def __str__(self):
    if len(self.members) == 0:
        return "{}"
    return "{" + ", ".join(str(e) for e in self.members) + "}"

def __add__(self, other):
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(other.members):
        if other.members[counter] not in self.members:
            self.members.append(other.members[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
    return self.members

def intersect(self, x):
    counter = 0
    answer = Set()
    while counter < len(x.members):
        if x.members[counter] in self.members: answer.members.append(x.members[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
    return answer

#No clue if this is what is intended
def has_subset(self, x):
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(x.members):
        if x.members[counter] not in self.members: return False
        counter = counter + 1
    return True
```

Here is the driver file:

```
    from Set import *

first = Set()
count = 0
while count < 10:
    first.add_element(count)
    count += 1
print(first)

second = Set()
count = 5
while count < 15:
    second.add_element(count)
    count += 1
print(second)    

third = Set()
third.add_element(2)
third.add_element(1)
third.add_element(8)
third.add_element(5)

#Tests has_subset with a set that is a subset
if first.has_subset(third):
    print(third, "is a subset of", first)
else:
    print(third, "is not a subset of", first)

#Tests has_subset with a set that is not a subset
if second.has_subset(third):
    print(third, "is a subset of", second)
else:
    print(third, "is not a subset of", second)

#Tests overloaded +
fourth = first + second
print(first, "+", second, "=\n", fourth)

#Tests intersect
fifth = first.intersect(second)
print(fifth, "is the intersection of", first, "and\n", second)
```

And here is the output:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
({2, 1, 8, 5}, 'is a subset of', {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
({2, 1, 8, 5}, 'is not a subset of', {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14})
({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, '+', {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, '=\n', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
({5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 'is the intersection of', {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 'and\n', {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14})
```

Notice how the first two lines are properly formatted with no parenthesis, but once additional strings are combined, the unwanted punctuation comes into play. How do I create output by only editing the Set class to remove this unwanted output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your Set class -- the problem is with how you're printing your content.

I suspect you're using Python 2.x?

If so, when you do `print(third, "is a subset of", second)`, you're actually telling Python to print the tuple (which contains 3 elements). Python obliges, and prints the parens and commas since that's part of printing a tuple. `print(...)` isn't a function in Python 2.

To fix this, you can either manually add together each piece:

```
print str(third) + ' is a subset of ' + str(second)
```

...or use string formatting:

```
print '{} is a subset of {}'.format(third, second)
```

...or add the line `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your driver file to include Python 3 printing semantics, which *does* turn `print(...)` into a function and does what you want.

Comment: using: `print "{third} is a subset of {second}".format(third=third, second=second)` is preferred over concatenation.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. Does that mean my version of python is outdated...?

Comment: @quintillion - well, yes and no. Technically, Python 3 is the latest version, but many people still use Python 2 since a lot of popular libraries they use haven't migrated over to Python 3 yet. Thankfully, the difference between them is pretty small, so it's typically easy to switch back and forth between the two. The only main incompatibility between the two is how they handle unicode text -- for everything else, you can import the appropriate backfixes from the `__future__` module.

Comment: It looks like you are using python 3 as in your code you are using the print function and not the print statement. That code would throw a syntax error if ran with the python 2 intepreter. You can double check this by typing python --version at the terminal. Either way @agconti answer is correct but you need to change it to the function syntax for python 3, namely `print ("{third} is a subset of {second}".format(third=third, second=second))`. That's just surrounding what you are printing with parens.

Comment: @b10n -- that's incorrect. If he were using Python 3, his code would be outputted properly (as a single string), and not as a tuple. Currently, to the best of my knowledge, the output of his code is consistent with the behavior you would expect if he were using Python 2 but inadvertently used Python 3 syntax.

Comment: Yep @Michael0x2a is correct, and i'm wrong. Shoulda checked before posting.

Comment: Well, I'm a little confused now. I updated to python 3.4.1 from the website but I still receive the same incorrect output...

Comment: @quintillion -- are you sure you're actually using Python 3? If you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, there's a chance you're accidentally using the wrong one.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Then no, I am not sure at all... I've definitely downloaded and installed it, but I have no clue how I would choose one or the other. I assumed the 2.x version would be replaced by the installed 3.4.1. If it matters, I'm building code in xcode and saving as .py files to run from the Terminal application on OS X.

Comment: @quintillion -- I think on macs, Python 2 is the default/used internally within the operating system, so don't try and uninstall that. Instead, try doing `python3 my_file.py` and see if that works.

Comment: @quintillion I recommend you use anaconda or homebrew to manage you python installation rather than the installers from the offical website. You can check out this for some best practices on [installing](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/). It can be very frustrating to run into multiple versions and PATH problems with python, and its a lesson i've learned myself the hard way.